# Parse an XML file which has multiple concatenated XML files within it

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, pandas, parsing

I am trying to parse an XML file which contains multiple XML files within the one XML file. I want to be able to parse over the main file (6+ million lines - dont worry I won't post that on here!) and return certain info from each of the XML files within each section.

The code looks like this (I have copied the first xml file 3 times to give you an idea of what the file looks like that I am working with but the main document I have has 6000 of these xml files all in one file which I need to parse to get the following out of see below xml file)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE us-patent-application SYSTEM "us-patent-application-v44-2014-04-03.dtd" [ ]>
    <us-patent-application lang="EN" dtd-version="v4.4 2014-04-03" file="US20180213710A1-20180802.XML" status="PRODUCTION" id="us-patent-application" country="US" date-produced="20180718" date-publ="20180802">
    <us-bibliographic-data-application lang="EN" country="US">
    <publication-reference>
    <document-id>
    <doc-number>20180213710</doc-number>
    <kind>A1</kind>
    <date>20180802</date>
    </document-id>
    </publication-reference>
    <application-reference appl-type="utility">
    <document-id>
    <country>US</country>
    <doc-number>15419046</doc-number>
    <date>20170130</date>
    </document-id>
    <invention-title id="d2e43">AGRICULTURAL IMPLEMENT WITH RELEASABLE TOOLS</invention-title>
    <assignees>
    <assignee>
    <addressbook>
    <orgname>CNH Industrial Canada, Ltd.</orgname>
    <role>03</role>
    <address>
    <city>Saskatoon</city>
    <country>CA</country>
    </address>
    </addressbook>
    </assignee>
    </assignees>
    </us-bibliographic-data-application>
    <abstract id="abstract">
    <p id="p-0001" num="0000">An agricultural implement includes a frame; a shank mounted to the frame and including at least one clip edge; a retaining clip press fitted to the at least one clip edge and including a movable lock biased in a locking direction; and a ground working tool with a locking opening at least partially filled by the movable lock to resist the tool being removed from the shank</p>
    </abstract>
    <us-claim-statement>What is claimed is:</us-claim-statement>
    </us-patent-application>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE us-patent-application SYSTEM "us-patent-application-v44-2014-04-03.dtd" [ ]>
    <us-patent-application lang="EN" dtd-version="v4.4 2014-04-03" file="US20180213710A1-20180802.XML" status="PRODUCTION" id="us-patent-application" country="US" date-produced="20180718" date-publ="20180802">
    <us-bibliographic-data-application lang="EN" country="US">
    <publication-reference>
    <document-id>
    <doc-number>20180213710</doc-number>
    <kind>A1</kind>
    <date>20180802</date>
    </document-id>
    </publication-reference>
    <application-reference appl-type="utility">
    <document-id>
    <country>US</country>
    <doc-number>15419046</doc-number>
    <date>20170130</date>
    </document-id>
    <invention-title id="d2e43">AGRICULTURAL IMPLEMENT WITH RELEASABLE TOOLS</invention-title>
    <assignees>
    <assignee>
    <addressbook>
    <orgname>CNH Industrial Canada, Ltd.</orgname>
    <role>03</role>
    <address>
    <city>Saskatoon</city>
    <country>CA</country>
    </address>
    </addressbook>
    </assignee>
    </assignees>
    </us-bibliographic-data-application>
    <abstract id="abstract">
    <p id="p-0001" num="0000">An agricultural implement includes a frame; a shank mounted to the frame and including at least one clip edge; a retaining clip press fitted to the at least one clip edge and including a movable lock biased in a locking direction; and a ground working tool with a locking opening at least partially filled by the movable lock to resist the tool being removed from the shank</p>
    </abstract>
    <us-claim-statement>What is claimed is:</us-claim-statement>
    </us-patent-application>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE us-patent-application SYSTEM "us-patent-application-v44-2014-04-03.dtd" [ ]>
    <us-patent-application lang="EN" dtd-version="v4.4 2014-04-03" file="US20180213710A1-20180802.XML" status="PRODUCTION" id="us-patent-application" country="US" date-produced="20180718" date-publ="20180802">
    <us-bibliographic-data-application lang="EN" country="US">
    <publication-reference>
    <document-id>
    <doc-number>20180213710</doc-number>
    <kind>A1</kind>
    <date>20180802</date>
    </document-id>
    </publication-reference>
    <application-reference appl-type="utility">
    <document-id>
    <country>US</country>
    <doc-number>15419046</doc-number>
    <date>20170130</date>
    </document-id>
    <invention-title id="d2e43">AGRICULTURAL IMPLEMENT WITH RELEASABLE TOOLS</invention-title>
    <assignees>
    <assignee>
    <addressbook>
    <orgname>CNH Industrial Canada, Ltd.</orgname>
    <role>03</role>
    <address>
    <city>Saskatoon</city>
    <country>CA</country>
    </address>
    </addressbook>
    </assignee>
    </assignees>
    </us-bibliographic-data-application>
    <abstract id="abstract">
    <p id="p-0001" num="0000">An agricultural implement includes a frame; a shank mounted to the frame and including at least one clip edge; a retaining clip press fitted to the at least one clip edge and including a movable lock biased in a locking direction; and a ground working tool with a locking opening at least partially filled by the movable lock to resist the tool being removed from the shank</p>
    </abstract>
    <us-claim-statement>What is claimed is:</us-claim-statement>
    </us-patent-application>
```

My code:

```
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
    import pandas as pd


    parsed_xml = et.parse("25_pto_test.xml")
    dfcols = ['us_patent_app_number', 'kind_code', 'date', 'invention_title', 'assignee', 'abstract']
    df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)
    pto = {}


    us_patent_app_number = parsed_xml.find('us-bibliographic-data-application/publication-reference/document-id/doc-number')
    kind_code = parsed_xml.find('us-bibliographic-data-application/publication-reference/document-id/kind')
    date = parsed_xml.find('us-bibliographic-data-application/publication-reference/document-id/date')
    invention_title = parsed_xml.find('us-bibliographic-data-application/invention-title')
    assignee = parsed_xml.find('us-bibliographic-data-application/assignees/assignee/addressbook/orgname')
    abstract = parsed_xml.find('abstract/p')

    pto.update({'US_Patent_App_Number': us_patent_app_number.text, 'Kind_Code': kind_code.text, 'Date': date.text,
        'Invention_Title': invention_title.text, 'Company_Name': assignee.text, 'Abstract': abstract.text})

    pto_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pto, orient='index')
    pto_data = pto_data.transpose()
```

I can get my above code to parse through the first xml section within the main xml file and then it crashes out at the end of the first xml file and says junk after line x in document.

Can anyone help??

Comment: I don't know python well enough to give you actual code, but basically you need to break up the file into separate chunks BEFORE giving it to the XML parser; to do this "breaking up" it's probably simplest in this case to read the file line by line and detect the <?xml?> declarations; when you hit such a declaration you can construct the previous XML entity and pass it in some form to the XML parser. You will just have to hope that there's nothing evil in the XML content, e.g. something in a CDATA section that can be confused with an XML declaration.

Comment: I should add that concatenating XML documents into a single file like this is bad practice and you should get the originator to do things differently if you can. The usual technique is to embed the XML documents in a ZIP archive.